# Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to send an email from a desktop program I am developing. Here is the code I am using but I keep getting the error below :

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("thesma@gmail.com");
message.Subject = "This is the Subject line";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("ideas@gmail.com");
message.Body = "This is the message body";
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",578);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(message);
```

I can't seem to find out what the problem is...

Comment: Any exception? Or what's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the credentials for Gmail

```
var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername@gmail.com", "mypwd"),
    EnableSsl = true
};
client.Send("myusername@gmail.com", "myusername@gmail.com", "test", "testbody");
```

Answer (score 3):

Missing credentials most likely:

```
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ideas@gmail.com", "password");
```

So:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ideas@gmail.com", "Password");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Alternatively, you can store (almost all) this stuff in the `app.config`, though I'm not sure how secure you need it to be since the user/pass would be plainly visible to any user that opens the application's directory (and that file). For completion's sake:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="ideas@gmail.com">
      <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
               enableSsl="true"
               userName="ideas@gmail.com"
               password="password"
               port="587" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Answer (score 1):

Network credentials are very important, but sometimes we need to check if port `587` is blocked.

```
   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("jorgesys@gmail.com", "whocaresdupe");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        client.Send(mail);          
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
       Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Successfully Send...');if(alert){ window.location='SendEmail.aspx';}</script>");
    }
```

Comment: How does this directly check if Port is open?

Answer (score 0):

My company blocks desktop/laptops from sending email using a setting in McAfee.  Check the Windows Event view to see if there is an entry that an email was blocked.